Docker | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('172.31.0.2', 5435)
I'm trying to connect postgres to my application but got error
Postgre and my app are in containers
And when i'm trying to connect from app container to postgre container, i have such error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/vpn_bot/core/main.py", line 27, in check_subscription
2024-04-10 17:02:32     users = await get_all_users()
2024-04-10 17:02:32             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/vpn_bot/core/services/bot_services.py", line 28, in get_all_users
2024-04-10 17:02:32     users = await session.execute(query)
2024-04-10 17:02:32             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 435, in execute
2024-04-10 17:02:32     result = await greenlet_spawn(
2024-04-10 17:02:32              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 192, in greenlet_spawn
2024-04-10 17:02:32     result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
2024-04-10 17:02:32              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2232, in execute
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return self._execute_internal(
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2117, in _execute_internal
2024-04-10 17:02:32     conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1984, in _connection_for_bind
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return trans._connection_for_bind(engine, execution_options)
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "<string>", line 2, in _connection_for_bind
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 137, in _go
2024-04-10 17:02:32     ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
2024-04-10 17:02:32                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1111, in _connection_for_bind
2024-04-10 17:02:32     conn = bind.connect()
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3269, in connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return self._connection_cls(self)
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
2024-04-10 17:02:32     self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
2024-04-10 17:02:32                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3293, in raw_connection
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return self.pool.connect()
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1268, in _checkout
2024-04-10 17:02:32     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
2024-04-10 17:02:32             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
2024-04-10 17:02:32     rec = pool._do_get()
2024-04-10 17:02:32           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 168, in _do_get
2024-04-10 17:02:32     with util.safe_reraise():
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
2024-04-10 17:02:32     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return self._create_connection()
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
2024-04-10 17:02:32     self.__connect()
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 902, in __connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     with util.safe_reraise():
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
2024-04-10 17:02:32     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
2024-04-10 17:02:32                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 895, in connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     await_only(self.asyncpg.connect(*arg, **kw)),
2024-04-10 17:02:32     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 126, in await_only
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return current.driver.switch(awaitable)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 187, in greenlet_spawn
2024-04-10 17:02:32     value = await result
2024-04-10 17:02:32             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 2092, in connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return await connect_utils._connect(
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 895, in _connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     raise last_error
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 881, in _connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return await _connect_addr(
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 773, in _connect_addr
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return await __connect_addr(params, timeout, True, *args)
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 825, in __connect_addr
2024-04-10 17:02:32     tr, pr = await compat.wait_for(connector, timeout=timeout)
2024-04-10 17:02:32              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/compat.py", line 56, in wait_for
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout)
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/tasks.py", line 489, in wait_for
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return fut.result()
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vpn-bot-bOMuw32Y-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 684, in _create_ssl_connection
2024-04-10 17:02:32     tr, pr = await loop.create_connection(
2024-04-10 17:02:32              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1086, in create_connection
2024-04-10 17:02:32     raise exceptions[0]
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1070, in create_connection
2024-04-10 17:02:32     sock = await self._connect_sock(
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 974, in _connect_sock
2024-04-10 17:02:32     await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 638, in sock_connect
2024-04-10 17:02:32     return await fut
2024-04-10 17:02:32            ^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-10 17:02:32   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 678, in _sock_connect_cb
2024-04-10 17:02:32     raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
2024-04-10 17:02:32 ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('172.31.0.2', 5435)

This is my docker compose file
version: '3.9'

services:
  bot_service:
    container_name: bot_service
    build: 
      context: .
    restart: always
    networks:
      - bot_net
    depends_on:
      - db_service

  db_service:
    container_name: db_service
    image: postgres:15.0-alpine3.16
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=vpn_db
      - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pgpass
      - POSTGRES_USER=pguser
    restart: always
    networks:
      - bot_net
    volumes:
      - db_data_bot:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db_data_bot:

networks:
  bot_net:
    driver: bridge

I have no any idea how to solve that?
I've checked a few post and saw that many suggested this is because there is no some networks. I know that postgre and my app inside the same network

You're connecting to port 5435, but you need the standard PostgreSQL port 5432.  Connections between containers don't use or require ports:.

ports are set in docker compose file:
ports: - "5435:5432"

Right, and connections between containers completely ignore those settings.

Have you tried to check your Postgres and your App containers if they're on the same network, by doing : docker inspect command, if yes?
I think the problem is on your Application code, try to use “psycopg2” to connect your app with Postgres, and don't forget to add the package on your requirements.txt file and install it inside the App containers.
I hope it will help.
Best regards.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
